# Function Prototype

Tags: c++, function

My teacher said that [A] was the correct ans but why isnt it [C]. whats wrong with option [B] as a prototype. Option [B] looks perfectly fine to me

> Which of the following function prototype is perfectly acceptable?
>
> [A].    `int Function(int Tmp = Show());`
>
> [B].   `float Function(int Tmp = Show(int, float));`
>
> [C].   Both A and B.
>
> [D].  `float = Show(int, float) Function(Tmp);`

Comment: Try compiling them all and see what errors/warnings you get.

Comment: i get two errors: default argurment not at end of parameter list and type name is not allowed. What does it mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
float Function(int Tmp = Show(int, float));
```

This defines a function called `Function` that returns a `float` and takes one argument that is an `int` called `Tmp`. The `Tmp` is being given a default value, but the default value is the part that is invalid. What value is `Show(int, float)`? It appears to be wanting to call a function called `Show` (or construct a temporary object of type `Show`), passing `int` and `float` as arguments. But `int` and `float` are not valid arguments to a function.

In fact, there are only a few places I can think of `Show(int, float)` being a possible production of the C++ grammar (without using the preprocessor). First is as part of a function declaration for `Show`. For example:

```
int Show(int, float);
```

Second is, if `Show` is a type, giving a function type. For example in:

```
foo<Show(int,float)>();
```

There are probably a few other similar cases, none of which actually call a function called `Show`.

Comment: why wouldnt int and float be valid argument to a function??? I thought all that matters is that the function Show returns a int value??

Comment: @Lim Because a default argument must be given some default value. For example `float Function(int Tmp = 5);` is fine. The `Tmp` argument will have a default value of `5`. For a function call to `Show` to work, you would have to do something like `float Function(int Tmp = Show(5, 6.0f));`